# Tiff iText filter for windows 2008 ent (not  R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, ocr

I would like to ocr and index tiff files on my windows 2008 server. Is there any way to install tiff iText filter available for Win 2008 R2?

Comment: The title is quite confusing, you don't want an answer that applies to any of the server2008 release, although in the question you mention both?

Comment: I have got windows 2008 instalation not R1 or R2. In feature wizard I don't have OCR Tiff feature. I would like to ocr my tiff files for sharepoint 2010

Comment: There is no such thing as an R1 release, R2 simply means Release 2, thus the original would rightfully be considered R1, as it is the first release in the windows 2008 family

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you can't use the R2 TIFF iFilter on "vanilla" Windows Server 2008. You could look around for thrid party solutions. OpenText [has one](http://www.opentext.com/uk/global/products/sol-pro-capture-delivery/products-opentext-tiff-ifilter.htm), but I don't know the system requirements.

I would consider upgrading to R2.

Comment: Page Not Found
We're sorry but the page you requested cannot be found; it may no longer exist or it has moved.